# Help to join two tables in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, join

I have two table. `user` and `address`. I  am joining them like this in zend:

```
$table = new Model_User_DbTable();
$select = $table->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck( false );
$select->join( 'address', 'address.id = user.address_id', array( 'city' => 'address.city' ) );
$row = $table->fetchAll( $select );
return $row;
```

But above query is returning all addresses from address but not data from user table. When I remove `$select->join( 'address', 'address.id = user.address_id', array( 'city' => 'address.city' ) );` then it shows only user table data.

How to get Both table's data??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested:

```
$table = new Model_User_DbTable();
$resultSet = $table->fetchAll($table->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('u'=>'user'))
    ->join(array('a'=>'address'), 'u.address_id = a.id', array('city'=>'address_city'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
$select = $table->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
```

Comment: print SQL query for debugging it